# concatening a variable to a file using cat

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, cat, linux-terminal

I wanted to do a bash function that given a text variable, it would concatenate it to a file. i.e

```
function print() {
cat << 'EOF' >> file
This $1 is a variable 
EOF
}
```

But it wouldnt work. It would always output `This $1 is a variable`.

I tried `${1}`, `{$1}`, `'$1'`, `"$1"`,and combinations of those, none worked. Is there some sort of special syntax, or should I use another command... what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unquote EOF:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function print() {
cat << EOF >> file
This $1 is a variable 
EOF
}

print stuff
```

In `man bash` it says under `Here Documents`:

> If word is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to
> parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion,
> the character sequence <newline> is ignored, and \ must be used to
> quote the characters , $, and `.